# Как вывести полученные ajax'ом данные

Tags: javascript, yii2

Есть файл корзины, js-файл и файл "бекенда".

К файлу корзины подключён следующий js-файл

```
let data_id_prod = localStorage.getItem('products');
console.log(data_id_prod);

if (data_id_prod === null) {
    document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = ('Ваша корзина пуста!');
}
else if (data_id_prod > '0') {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://frontend/answer/" + data_id_prod,
        data:  {$data_id_prod: data_id_prod},
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
}
```

В нём сначала идёт проверка переменной, после чего, если она пуста, в div, с классом "out" выводится/заменяется строчка. Если же в ней есть значение, то данная переменная отправляется ajax'ом на "бекенд". С "бекенда" приходит ответ формата JSON с нужными мне данными. Вопрос в том, как мне эти данные вывести на страницу html? А точнее, что нужно написать тут:

```
success: function(data) {
        }
```

Код бекенда:

```
public function actionAnswer($data_id_prod)
    {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $id_prod = Products::find()
        ->select([
            'product_name',
            'product_price',
        ])
        ->where([
            'ID' => $data_id_prod
        ])
        ->one();
//        var_dump($id_prod);
//        return;
        return [
            'id_prod' => $id_prod
        ];
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте формат в коде бекенда поменять на FORMAT_HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json', // <------
    ...
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: ну до этого я и сам догадался) Мне бы узнать, как правильно вывести их на страничку. Использовав innerHTML или что-то подобное. К примеру, через createElement создать div и в него прописать innerHTML с пришедшими данными.

Comment: @Awake https://api.jquery.com/html/